# Higher Algebra, Theorem 2.4.3.18 and Remark 2.4.3.6

Tags: ct.category-theory, simplicial-stuff, infinity-categories, higher-algebra

In his book *Higher Algebra*, Lurie introduces the notion of **generalized $\infty$-operads** ($\S$2.3.2). Roughly speaking, a generalized $\infty$-operad is a "family" of $\infty$-operads parametrized by an $\infty$-category. If $\mathcal{O}^\otimes$ is a generalized $\infty$-operad and $\mathcal{O}^{\prime\otimes}$ is an $\infty$-operad, a morphism $f:\mathcal{O}^\otimes \to\mathcal{O}^{\prime\otimes}$ of generalized $\infty$-operads is said to **assemble** $\mathcal{O}^\otimes $ to $\mathcal{O}^{\prime\otimes}$ if for each $\infty$-operad $\mathcal{O}^{\prime\prime\otimes}$, the functor
$$\operatorname{Alg}_{\mathcal{O}'}(\mathcal{O}^{\prime \prime})\to\operatorname{Alg}_{\mathcal{O}}(\mathcal{O}^{\prime\prime})$$

is an equivalence of $\infty$-categories (Definition 2.3.3.1). Lurie gives a practical condition which guarantees that $f$ is an assemble map; namely, if $f$ is a **weak approximation** and induces an equivalence of $\infty$-categories $\mathcal{O}^\otimes_{\langle1\rangle}\to\mathcal{O}^{\prime\otimes} _{\langle 1\rangle}$, then $f$ assembles $\mathcal{O}^\otimes $to $\mathcal{O}^{\prime\otimes}$ (Theorem 2.3.3.23). (Lurie also introduces a class of maps called approximations, and every approximation is a weak approximation. The definitions of approximations and weak approximations can be found in Definition 2.3.3.6.)

Now given an $\infty$-category  $\mathcal{C}$, we can define an $\infty$-operad $\mathcal{C}^\amalg$ by the universal property
$$\operatorname{Fun}_{N(\mathcal{F}\mathrm{in}_\ast)}(K,\mathcal{C}^\amalg)\cong\operatorname{Fun}(K\times_{N(\mathcal{F}\mathrm{in}_\ast)}N(\Gamma^\ast),\mathcal{C}),$$where $\Gamma^*$ is the category of elements of the functor $\mathcal{F}\mathrm{in}_\ast\to\mathcal{S}\mathrm{et}$. Roughly speaking, the $\infty$-operad $\mathcal{C}^\amalg$ is something like a symmetric multicategory whose objects are the objects of $C$, and whose spaces of operations $(C_1,\dots,C_n)\to D$ are given by the product $\prod_{1\leq i\leq n}\operatorname{Map}_{\mathcal{C}}(C_i,D)$. The projection $\Gamma^*\to\mathcal{F}\mathrm{in}_\ast$ induces a functor $f:\mathcal{C}\times N(\mathcal{F}\mathrm{in}_\ast)\to\mathcal{C}^\amalg$. It is a key ingredient of Theorem 2.4.3.18 that this map is a weak approximation. (In fact, Lurie asserts that it is an approximation, but we only need it to be a weak approximation here.) According to Remark 2.4.3.6, this follows by "unwinding the definitions," noting that $\mathcal{C}^\amalg_{\langle n \rangle/C}$ has a terminal object. I understand that the $\infty$-category $\mathcal{C}^\amalg_{\langle n \rangle/C}$ has a final object, **but I do not understand how it has anything to do with the fact that $f$ is a (weak) approximation.** Can anyone enlighten me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I agree something seems fishy. If I understand correctly, suppose that $(a,b) \to (c)$ corresponds to maps $a,b \to c$. Then if $f$ is a weak approximation it would be the case that the category of factorizations $(a,b)\to (d,...,d) \to (c)$, where the first map is inert and the second map comes from $\mathcal{C} \times \mathrm{Fin}_*$, would have to be contractible. As far as I can tell this category is empty if $a$ and $b$ are not isomorphic? Am I misunderstanding what the functor $f$ does somehow? I guess in terms of 2.3.3.11 I'm saying that the category in the 2nd condition is often empty.

Comment: @DylanWilson Yes, I was thinking about the same sort of things. Something is wrong unless we are both mistaken.

Comment: Algebras for $\mathcal{C} \times \mathrm{Fin}_*$ in $\mathcal{O}$ are functors from $\mathcal{C}$ to commutative algebras in $\mathcal{O}$. An $\infty$-operad with the same property is the Boardman-Vogt tensor of $\mathrm{Fin}_*$ with the $\infty$-operad "$\mathcal{C}_{\mathrm{opd}}$" with only unary operations given by $\mathcal{C}$  (explicitly it is the cocartesian fibration over the inert subcategory of $\mathrm{Fin}_*$ for the right Kan extension along the inclusion of the object <1> of the functor with value $\mathcal{C}$, or $\mathcal{C}^\amalg$ pulled back to the inert subcategory).

Comment: The Boardman-Vogt tensor can be modelled by $\mathrm{Fin}_* \times \mathcal{C}_{\mathrm{opd}}$ (over the "smash product" $\mathrm{Fin}_* \times \mathrm{Fin}_* \rightarrow \mathrm{Fin}_*$), or by the wreath product. These look like they stand a better chance of being an approximation to $\mathcal{C}^{\amalg}$...

Comment: Ok I deleted my answer (Ken pointed out an error). I'm either making a mistake or neither option from Rune's post gives an approximation. So I don't see a fix (for this or the related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/394867/understanding-the-disintegration-of-unital-infty-operads])

Comment: Here is a partial answer. In some of Higher Algebra (e.g. much of disintegration/assembly), we have that $\mathcal{C}$ is an $\infty$-groupoid $X$. In that case the map $X \times \mathrm{Fin}_\ast \to X^\coprod$ is an approximation: (1) of 2.3.3.6 is automatic, and for (2) use that since every active morphism with target $\{c\}_{i \in I}$ is equivalent to one of the form $\{c\}_{j \in J} \to \{c\}_{i \in I}$ with $\alpha \colon J \to I$ active and all maps $c \to c$ the identity, one can just take the pair $(\alpha,\mathrm{id}_c)$ to be the cartesian lift, if I didn't make a mistake.

Comment: @skupers Thanks! Your comment is very helpful. I don't think we can just check (2) of 2.3.3.6 because $f:X\times \mathrm{Fin}_\ast\to X^\amalg$ is not a categorical fibration (it is almost never an isofibration), but things look much promising under the assumption that $\mathcal{C}$ is an $\infty$-groupoid.  (If we only care about whether or not $f$ is a *weak* approximation, we may also resort to 2.3.3.16.)